# In a new line, moving to the columns of the beginning of the words in the line above?

Tags: cursor-movement, cursor-motions

Is it possible to have a 'smart tab' working as follows: 'move forward to the columns corresponding to the beginnings of the words in the line above'

For example, in the situation below:

[image]

I would like a 'smart tab' that, pressed once would move to the column below the '=' sign, and pressed twice would move to the  column below the 'b' in 'basepoint' in the line above.

Currently I do this by pressing the regular 'tab' and pressing the space bar as required, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way, especially as the programming language I am using requires me to save tabs as spaces.

Comment: If you have `tabs` around the `=` sign, that's what should happen. The `softtabstop` option being responsible for the 'length' of a tab, so you only can only align with tabs on columns which are a multiple of `softtabstop` value. I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Although that's not the answer to your question, it might be interesting to have a look into the plugins [`vim-lion`](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-lion) or [`tabular`](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular).  Both of them allow you to reformat the text so that you align it according to specific characters, e.g. `=`, and both of them are written only in `vimscript`.

Example of usage `vim-lion`:

```
some header = test
  a = 42
  morethana = 43
  somethingelse = 17
```

if you now put your cursor in the line `a = 42` and press `gl)=`, the output will change to

```
some header = asdf
  a             = 42
  morethana     = 43
  somethingelse = 17
```

The `)`-part is composable, so that you could also use `ip` to change it to the whole paragraph regardless on where your cursor is positioned.

Similarly, you could use `tabular` by visually selecting the desired lines and write `:Tabularize /=` to align all the `=`.  If you don't select anything, the alignment will be used for the overall paragraph.  Although this is a more verbose way to do it compared to the `vim-lion`-way, you can also align by character-combinations (e.g. `<-` as used in `GNU R`).